# É possível enviar todas as Exceptions java por email?

Tags: java, spring, exceção, spring-mvc, envio-de-email

Tenho uma aplicação Java Web, utilizando Spring MVC, e gostaria de enviar por email todas as Exceptions lançadas no sistema.

É possível fazer isso? Configurar um e-mail padrão para que receba todas as Exceptions e o stacktrace, para que eu acompanhe os possíveis erros que acontecerem?

Comment: **Não faça isso**, a não ser que seu sistema tenha apenas um ou dois usuários e nenhum processamento pesado. Se tiver algo mais que isso, logo vai estourar a caixa de e-mail de alguém, o limite de envio, vai deixar o sistema mais lento e vai encher tanto o saco que logo vão desabilitar o processo. Dependendo do quão crítico é o processo, você pode selecionar alguns tipos de erros críticos e colocar numa fila ou tabela ou mesmo nos logs e manter um outro processo agendado que coleta a informação e notifica o responsável quando houver algo relevante. Erros básicos devem ser pegos em testes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Usando Spring MVC**

O Spring MVC fornece uma maneira de lidar com exceções, a anotação [@ExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) . Para cada controlador podemos definir um método que é chamado quando determinada exceção é lançada.

Primeiro é preciso criar uma classe e colocar a anotação [@ControllerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html). Esta anotação é usada para definir métodos `@ExceptionHandler`, `@InitBinder` e `@ModelAttribute` que se aplicam a todos os métodos anotados com `@RequestMapping`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SendMailExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    protected SendMailService sendMailService;

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView exceptionHanlder(Exception  ex) {
        String mensagem = "Ocorreu um erro no sistema xyz: " + ex.getMessage();
        sendMailService.send(mensagem);

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("exception", exception);
        mv.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        mv.setViewName("error");

        return mv;
    }
}
```

No `@ExceptionHandler` você passa qual é a classe de Exceção que aquele método vai interceptar nos controllers.

A vantagem é que você não precisar usar `try catch` nos seus controllers e além de enviar o e-mail o método vai redirecionar o usuário para uma página que você deseja, uma página de erro padrão por exemplo.

Essa abordagem não capturam erros de outras chamadas que não passam pelo controller, por exemplo você tem uma execução automática de tempos em tempos que acaba gerando uma exceção e nesse caso o `@ExceptionHandler` não vai capturar.

**Usando AOP**
Com Spring, você pode escrever um interceptor [AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) :

```
@Aspect
public class ErrorInterceptor{

   SendMailService sendMailService;

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* br.com..* (..))", throwing = "ex")
public void errorInterceptor(Exception ex) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Interceptor inicializado");
    }


    String mensagem = "Ocorreu um erro no sistema xyz. " + ex.getMessage();
    sendMailService.send(mensagem);


    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Interceptor finalizado.");
    }
}
}
```

Com o AOP você pode interceptar as exceções que ocorrem em determinado pacote. Se não conhece AOP recomendo ler a [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

Fontes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947933/aop-exception-handling
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: No caso do AOP, eu crio essa classe ErrorInterceptor do seu exemplo, e preciso colocar algo nos meus Controllers? Ou ele realmente intercepta as exceções que ocorrerem no pacote que eu definir?

Comment: Não precisa colocar nada no seu controller se usar AOP e ele só vai interceptar o que está no pacote que você definiu. No exemplo ele vai interceptar todos os pacotes que começam com br.com

Comment: Então acho que é perfeito pra minha situação. E ele interceptará qualquer exceção, correto? Independente de qual for. Muito obrigado pela sua atenção, não conhecia esses assuntos!

Comment: Criei a classe e fiz um teste com um breakpoint nela, mas nem bateu lá. Preciso configurar algo mais além de criar a classe?